# Combine fields with overlapping dates into one field (qlik sense)

Tags: overlapping, dbeaver, qliksense

Hello to the whole community!

There is a code that combine many field with overlapping dates into one field.

The code is below

```
Table_one:

load *

INLINE [

id_client | id_question| date_open | date_close

YZIYR00R | 14534534 | 05.10.2022 | 30.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 14786543 | 26.10.2022 | 27.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 87634957 | 27.10.2022 | 28.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 12398750 | 27.10.2022 | 28.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 57548555 | 27.10.2022 | 28.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 36485023 | 29.10.2022 | 30.10.2022

] (delimiter is '|');



Tmp:

LOAD *, if(previous(date_close) >= date_open and previous(id_client) = id_client,

peek(question_group), id_question) as question_group

Resident Table_one

ORDER BY id_client, date_open, date_close;

drop table Table_one;



SampleData:

LOAD id_client, question_group as id_question,

FirstSortedValue(date_open, recno()) as date_open,

FirstSortedValue(date_close, -recno()) as date_close

Resident Tmp

GROUP BY id_client, question_group;

drop table Tmp;
```

So the last line doesn’t fall in the interval. The problem is that the code only checks the previous and next lines, if you add the filed (my last line in code), it will not fall into the interval because is compared to the previous one.
And I would like the intersecting intervals to join one, where the start date would be the minimum number of the intersecting group and the end date would be the maximum.
Than I wrote the next following code:

```
Table_one:

load *

INLINE [

id_client | id_question| date_open | date_close

YZIYR00R | 14534534 | 11.01.2022 | 11.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 14786543 | 11.01.2022 | 11.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 87634957 | 11.01.2022 | 11.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 12398750 | 11.01.2022 | 12.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 57548555 | 13.01.2022 | 13.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 36485023 | 13.01.2022 | 14.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 09748361 | 13.01.2022 | 13.01.2022

YZIYR00R | 56419453 | 13.01.2022 | 15.01.2022





] (delimiter is '|');




Tmp:

LOAD *, if(previous(date_close) >= date_open and previous(id_client) = id_client,

peek(question_group), id_question) as question_group

Resident Table_one

ORDER BY id_client,date_close,date_open;

drop table Table_one;





next:

load id_client, question_group as id_question, min(date_open) as date_open, max(date_close) as date_close

Resident Tmp

Group by id_client, question_group;

drop table Tmp;
```

but with the data below it will no longer work correctly:

```
Table_one:

load *

INLINE [

id_client | id_question| date_open | date_close

YZIYR00R | 14534534 | 03.10.2022 | 03.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 14786543 | 04.10.2022 | 04.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 87634957 | 05.10.2022 | 02.12.2022

YZIYR00R | 12398750 | 06.10.2022 | 05.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 57548555 | 08.10.2022 | 06.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 36485023 | 17.10.2022 | 11.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 09748361 | 19.10.2022 | 18.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 56419453 | 20.10.2022 | 19.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 64324123 | 31.10.2022 | 26.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 53634322 | 01.11.2022 | 31.10.2022

YZIYR00R | 56787656 | 03.11.2022 | 03.11.2022

YZIYR00R | 78946487 | 09.11.2022 | 03.11.2022

YZIYR00R | 11111111 | 09.11.2022 | 09.11.2022

YZIYR00R | 98541484 | 10.11.2022 | 11.11.2022

YZIYR00R | 45487874 | 29.11.2022 | 23.11.2022

YZIYR00R | 26548459 | 02.12.2022 | 29.11.2022

] (delimiter is '|');
```

Comment: Postgres does not have `LOAD` so what database are you using?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Qlik Sense

Comment: Then remove the Postgres tag.